# How to initialize Autocomplete component with all options checked

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I have an `Autocomplete` component where in addition a "Select All" option has been implemented.

I would like all the options to be selected when the component first initializes, along with the "Select All" option.

I have tried setting the `defaultValue` option to my initial options and that did not work.
I have tried initializing my `selectedOptions` to be the same as my input `options` and that also did not work.

Here is my [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-material-ui-autocomplete-select-all-forked-4v44cj).

```
const DataFilteringSelection = (props: DataFilteringSelectionType): JSX.Element => {
  const classes = useStyles();

  const { label, placeholder, options, selectAllLabel, startWithAllSelected, sendSelectedOptions } = props;

  const filter = createFilterOptions();

  const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = React.useState<FilterDefinitionType[]>([]);
  const [prevSelectedOptions, setPrevSelectedOptions] = React.useState<FilterDefinitionType[]>([]);
  const allSelected = options.length === selectedOptions.length;

  const handleToggleOption = (selected: FilterDefinitionType[]) => setSelectedOptions(selected);
  const handleClearOptions = () => setSelectedOptions([]);

  const handleSelectAll = (isSelected: boolean): void => {
    if (isSelected) {
      setSelectedOptions(options);
    }
    else {
      handleClearOptions();
    }
  };

  const handleToggleSelectAll = (): void => {
    handleSelectAll(!allSelected);
  };

  const handleDataFilteringSelectionChange = (event: React.ChangeEvent<{}>, selected: FilterDefinitionType[], reason: AutocompleteChangeReason): void => {
    if (reason === 'select-option' || reason === 'remove-option') {
      if (selected.find((option) => option.name === selectAllLabel)) {
        handleToggleSelectAll();
      }
      else {
        handleToggleOption(selected);
      }
    }

    if (reason === 'clear') {
      handleClearOptions();
    }
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Autocomplete
        multiple
        disableCloseOnSelect
        disableClearable
        fullWidth
        onClose={handleDataFilteringSelectionDropdownClose}
        onChange={handleDataFilteringSelectionChange}
        options={options}
        filterOptions={(options: FilterDefinitionType[], params) => {
          const filtered: any[] = filter(options, params);
          return selectAllLabel ? [{ name: selectAllLabel }, ...filtered] : filtered;
        }}
        getOptionLabel={(option) => option.name}
        value={selectedOptions}
        renderInput={inputRenderer}
        renderOption={optionRenderer}
        renderTags={tagRenderer}
        PopperComponent={CustomPopper}
        PaperComponent={CustomPaper}
      />
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState([]);
const allSelected = items.length === selectedOptions.length;
```

When the component first renders, `allSelected` is false because `selectedOptions` is an empty array by default. You should set the default value to `items`.

```
const [selectedOptions, setSelectedOptions] = useState(items);
const allSelected = items.length === selectedOptions.length;
```